# Writing a value to memory on GBA using ASM THUMB

Tags: assembly, arm, game-boy-advance

Hey I am working on a simple university project and making a game for the GameBoy Advanced.

I have been playing around with asm, with intention to create my colour palettes via ASM and THUMB mode.

I have tried using `ldr` and `str` to load a memory adress `0x0500000` (palette memory) into a register and store a value such as `0x253F` (red colour) and store that into the palette adress. How could this be done? I tried using MOV too but also without success.

Below code compiles, but it doesn't seem to work

```
.THUMB              @ turn on thumb
.ALIGN  2           @ align code correctly for GBA
.GLOBL  test        @ name of function goes here

.THUMB_FUNC         @ we are about to declare a thumb function
test:               @ function start

push { r4-r7, lr }  @ push r4-r7 and link register onto stack. Your function might use these
                @ registers, so we need to preserve the values just in case!
                @ we don't need to worry about r0-r3 as it is assumed they will be regularly messed up anyway


@ the magic happens here!
@ r0-r3 will automatically contain the parameters sent when calling the function.


ldr r5, =#0x5000000
ldr r4, =#0x03DF
str r5, [r4]

pop { r4-r7 }       @ pop first 4 values from stack back into r4-r7, and also
pop { r3 }          @ pop the next value from stack (stored value for lr) into some unused register, e.g. r3 -
                @ we cannot overwrite lr so we have to do it via a normal register
bx r3               @ "branch and exchange" (return) back to C, using the     previous value for lr stored in r3
 @ ==================================
```

I really aprreciate any help

Comment: What's the exact nature of "doesn't seem to work"? Data abort? Undefined instruction? Memory contents unchanged? Corruption because you didn't actually want to store a whole 32-bit value? There are many, many possibilities, all for very different reasons.

Comment: memory contents unchanged, this code did nothing, any advice?

Comment: _"memory contents unchanged, this code did nothing"_ How did you verify this to be the case?

Comment: in the gameboy emulator (visual boy advance) you can view your colour palette, starting from memory 0x05000000 and moving in 16bit chunks of memory up to 0x0500001FE each 16bit chunk can hold a colour value e.g.0x39DD. So in my case after compiling the above code, my palette position at 0x050000E8 is not overwritten from 0x0000 default (black) value to  0x253F (red)

Comment: You need to be careful about terminology here. Nothing is going to happen just by _compiling_ the code. It doesn't do anything until you _run_ it. Anyway, the code works for me (I had to make certain assumptions about how you call your Thumb function, because you haven't shown us that). Have you pressed the Refresh button on the palette viewer window?

Comment: I added my full code, and yes i did press refresh, after I ran the code, still no clue how to fix it

Comment: okay it works, it might sound stupid, but I think i missed one 0 on the palette adres....

Comment: Your updated code stores the value `0x05000000` in address `0x03DF`. Also note that because the palette entries are 16-bit wide you should use the 16-bit store instruction STRH. With STR you're writing a 32-bit value which means you're modifying two palette entries.

Comment: Can't you return with `pop { r4-r7, pc }`, instead of that clumsy three-instruction sequence that pops `lr` into `r3` and then runs `bx r3`?  Of course, this function only needs two scratch regs, so you could take out all the pushes/pops, and use `r0` and `r1` instead of `r4` and `r5`.  Then the normal `bx lr` to return.

Comment: Besides that, why exactly would you go out of your way to avoid overwriting `lr` with _the same value it contained in the first place_ (and in this case still does)?